# Expand ~, . and `..`

Tags: shell, directory

Since `~`, `.` and `..` are special directories, why are they handled differently in the following example?

```
$ echo ~
/home/tim
$ echo ..
..
$ echo .
.
```

1. `~` is expanded into the dir, but the other two are not.
2. The other two are expanded literally, but `~` isn't.

Comment: `~` is not a directory, it is a construct of your shell and does not truly exist.

Comment: `.` is not (the name of) a directory either, but `~` refers to your home directory as `.` refers to the current directory and `..` refers to the parent directory.

Answer (score 18):

`~` is a special name expanded by the shell, `.` and `..` are real proper directory names, so no expansion is done by the shell there.

Comment: For example, type `ls -a` and you'll see the `.` and `..` directories. The only reason they're not usually shown is that anything beginning with `.` is hidden by default.

Comment: Another way to see the difference is to quote it: `ls -ld '~'` will give an error (unless there's a file of directory named `~` in the current directory) while `ls -ld '.'` will show information about the current directory.

Comment: +1 Might also be useful to mention the fact that `.` is a hard link to the current directory and `..` is a hard link to the current directory's parent.

Comment: `.` is *not* a directory name, unless you issue `mkdir '.'`