# Setting XDG_CACHE_HOME Breaks Firefox Installation

Tags: shell-script, firefox, xdg-user-dirs

In my `.bashrc` I set my `XDG_CACHE_HOME` variable to `"~/.cache/"`.

This breaks my Firefox installation, telling me that it cannot load my profile.

Without this line, Firefox loads properly.

I have tried `sudo -R chown $USER:$USER ~/.cache/mozilla` with no avail (same for my `.mozilla` folder).

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shells don't perform tilde expansion inside quotes, so your `"~/.cache"` doesn't point to your home directory—it points to a subdirectory `.cache` of a directory called `~`.

Remove the quotes, and everything should work as expected:

```
export XDG_CACHE_HOME=~/.cache
```

Comment: Oh man, that is hilarious. I was wondering what that random tilda folder doing in my home directory that had been generated was doing there! Thank you!