# readlink literal vs variable

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable-substitution, tilde

Using BASH: the answer is probably obvious but, not for me.

```
> echo $PWD
/root/fcm
> readlink -f ~
/root
> # but then with a variable or literal
> a='~'
> readlink -f $a
/root/fcm/~
> readlink -f "~"
/root/fcm/~
```

I'm expecting to receive just '/root/';
Who is doing the substitution bash or readlink?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell does the tilde expansion. `readlink` doesn't. [Bash will not expand tilde within quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes).

`readlink -f $a` does not do what you want as tilde expansion happens before variable expansion, i.e. the variable is expanded to `~`, but that tilde won't be expanded further.

The order in which Bash do things is: brace expansion,
       tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command
       substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname
       expansion.

Using `$HOME` may be preferable to using tilde under some circumstances, since it behaves as any other variable.

Also, please don't work logged in as root...