# How to leverage a user defined variable in a command to create a condition in an if

Tags: bash, variable, variable-substitution

I have a script which takes input for two variables from users. Then, I try to use those variables in a command which is in turn being fed into a condition in an if. However, the user input value is not replacing my variables and as a result, my command is not working -

```
# Get acl and dc values
echo "Type the ACL name:"
read acl
echo "Type the DATACENTER name"
read dc
# see if sw-list-cisco file exists in ~/$acl directory"
if [ ` ls -1 ~/$acl/sw-list-cisco > /dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 ];
then
    echo "Going to do something"
else
     echo "no match !!!!!!!!!!!!!"
fi
```

The `` if [ ` ls -1 ~/"$acl"/sw-list-cisco > /dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 ]; `` condition doesn't seem to be replacing $acl with the user input value. I have verified manually that `sw-list-cisco` exists in the `~/$acl` directory.  What am I missing?

Comment: If is not a loop (there is no iteration (repetition))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You rarely, if ever, need to parse the output from `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

In this case, you may get by by just doing

```
if [ -f "$HOME/$acl/sw-list-cisco" ]; then
```

I'm using the `-f` test to test whether the given name exists and is the name of a regular file.  I'm using `$HOME` rather than `~` since [`~` does not behave as a variable inside quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes) (and `$HOME` is much more descriptive, IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ ` ls -1 ~/$acl/sw-list-cisco > /dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 ];
```

You redirect the output of `ls` to `/dev/null`, so nothing goes to `wc`, and it always prints `0`. Same if you try it manually: `ls / >/dev/null | wc -l` vs. `ls / | wc -l`.

You probably wanted to redirect *errors* from `ls` to `/dev/null` instead:

```
if [ $(ls ~/"$acl/sw-list-cisco" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ];
```

(`-1` is not needed when the output goes to a pipe.)

But since it's just one file, `[ -f ~/"$acl/sw-list-cisco" ]` will do it more easily as [@Kusalananda already answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364798/170373). Even if you wanted a count of the files, it might be better to expand a glob to an array and count the elements.

Comment: And anything which uses `wc` in a condition is probably [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc).

Comment: @tripleee, though `ls` doesn't have a switch for counting and I don't think `find` has one either

Comment: Yeah, there's a corner case where you actually want to perform arithmetic on the actual number of matches; the real antipattern is comparing the count to nonzero when the shell already tells you whether something succeeded or not.