# cd && ls function doesn't work in other aliases before reloading .bashrc?

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following code in my `.bashrc`:

```
c() { cd "$@" && ls -a ; }
alias cdd="c ~/Downloads"
alias r=". ~/.bashrc"
```

When I load a new terminal, `cdd` doesn't work before I do the `r` command. But after doing so, it works as intended. Why is this?

I asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262620/cd-ls-function-doesnt-work-in-other-aliases-before-reloading-bashrc) on Stack Overflow a few months ago, but none of the responses were able to give me a working solution. [Here is the link to my dotfiles](https://github.com/Kevin-Mok/linux-config/tree/master/dotfiles) if that will be of any use.

**EDIT** `type -a c cdd r` produces:

```
c is aliased to `clear'
c is a function
c () 
{ 
    cd "$@" && ls --color=auto -a
}
cdd is aliased to `c ~/Downloads'
r is aliased to `. ~/.bashrc'
```

Based on this information, I changed the `c` function to `d`, and it works. That being said, is there any way I could not map the clear function to c as I already have `alias cs='printf "\033c"'` for that)? I looked in `.bashrc` but couldn't find anything with the word "clear".

Comment: Run `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' bash -lixc exit |& grep clear` and add the output, please.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting an output.

Comment: to remove the alias of c do `unalias c`, that's it. To find where that is being defined use [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420581/cd-ls-function-doesnt-work-in-other-aliases-before-reloading-bashrc#comment756195_420581) command and post output: `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' bash -lixc exit |& grep clear`

Comment: Probably comes from https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/956b3e417fa1a4066fd9248e9a01fedbc4544dfc/aliases/available/general.aliases.bash#L39

Comment: Ohh. Strange though, I don't have that line in my .bashrc yet it's still aliased  with every terminal launch.

Comment: Eh? You clearly are sourcing bash-it in your bashrc. It probably sets some environment variable that prevents it from being sourced again, so it didn't show up in the bash command I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

If the `c` is aliased to `clear` but not in your own shell initialization files, then it's most likely done in the system-wide initialization files under `/etc`.  Check, for example `/etc/bash.bashrc` (or see your `bash` manual for what files are used, this may differ between systems depending on how `bash` was built).

No matter where `c` is aliased to `clear`, you may unalias `c` before defining it as a function with

```
unalias c
```

You may also consider using `$HOME` in place of `~`. This is due to `$HOME` being more descriptive (and you don't actually need to type it out since it's part of an alias, so you don't "lose" anything), and that it behaves as a variable whereas `~` does not. See [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Comment: Weird. I added `unalias c`, but I get `bash: unalias: c: not found` even though it shows that it's still assigned to `clear` when I do `type -a c cdd r`.

Comment: @Kevin Then look further down in your `.bashrc` file to find where the `c` alias gets defined or where you source a file that defines it.