# Command 'which' not showing output for custom PATH locations

Tags: terminal, which

**Scenario**

I have a ProductivityScripts project on GitHub, and when I install Linux (Debian 9), I add this folder to `PATH` for ease of use.

I.e., I add the following line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="~/Dev/ProductivityScripts:$PATH"
```

It works. I can now run scripts from inside this folder by name from anywhere.

```
alec@my_host:~$ capsalt
SUCCESS!
```

However, if I type `which capsalt` I get no output.

`which`ing most things works.

```
alec@my_host:~$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

**Question**

Shouldn't `which` also track down scripts that are available from locations added to PATH manually? Or is there another reason why this isn't working?

Comment: What shell, and what OS are you using?

Comment: This was bash in Debian Stretch. (The question has been answered, but since it may be relevant for someone else at some point, may as well elaborate.)

Comment: TMUX isn't a shell. Your shell is something like `bash` or `zsh`.

Comment: Sorry. Then `bash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely due to `~` not acting as a variable inside double quotes in combination with `which` not doing its own expansion of the tilde.

Use

```
PATH="$HOME/Dev/ProductivityScripts:$PATH"
```

instead. `HOME` is an environment variable and expands as usual within double quotes. Note also that since `PATH` is already exported, it does not need to be exported again (through it does not hurt).

More information about tilde: [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: Yep, that solved it, thanks! Had no idea about the deal with tilde inside double quotes. Definitely a fact that will inevitably become relevant again and again.

Comment: @Alec My take on it is to _always_ use `$HOME` in scripts while using `~` only on the command line if my fingers happens to be tired (and it's not in a double quote). `$HOME` also has the benefit of being more self-documenting than tilde.

Comment: You know, I'm pretty sick of the finger-twisting I have to do to get the tilde character on a Norwegian keyboard layout. Since it's normally something you use oñ tõp õf other characters, I have to tap it twice to get `~` on its own. May just use `$HOME` for simplicity's sake, everywhere.