# Running gcc from prefix folder

Tags: gcc

I have a user account on RHEL 6.7. The built-in gcc does not support c++11, so I am trying to install my a more recent gcc. I have run configure with  `--prefix=$HOME/dependencies/gcc` , `make`, `make install`, and updated my environment variables:

```
declare -x LIBRARY_PATH="~/dependencies/gcc/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH"
declare -x PATH="~/dependencies/gcc/bin/:$PATH"
```

`gcc -v`  now shows the updated version (either 4.9.4 or 5.5.0, I have tried both), and `which gcc` shows the expected output:

```
[user@host ~]$ which gcc
~/dependencies/gcc/bin/gcc
```

The problem is the following:

```
[user@host ~]$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
[user@host ~]$ ~/dependencies/gcc/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
[user@host ~]$
```

I wonder why I have to give the full path to g++ to make this work. I could not debug this with `strace`, since `strace g++` runs the version from `/usr/bin`. Any ideas?

**Update** after adding a symlink as suggested by Knud Larsen, I ran `strace strace g++55` and noticed this line:

```
stat("~/dependencies/gcc/bin/g++55", 0x7ffcf17f9530) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

After replacing `~` in `PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` with `/home/user`, everything works well.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Try to switch  between the `gcc` versions through `/usr/sbin/alternatives --config gcc`

Comment: @GAD3R I do not have superuser access.

Comment: Post the output of `which g++`

Comment: Suggest : symlink gcc, g++ to a new name : `ln -s gcc gcc55` and `ln -s g++ g++55` ... And : only use the new names in commands. Then hopefully g++55 will use the right `cc1plus` ... ( The symlinks can have any locatation, e.g. `/home/[name]/bin/{ gcc55, g++55 }`.) The ideal configuration for gcc would have been option `--program-suffix=55`. I.e. an extra gcc shoudn't be named gcc.

Comment: @ajeh I have added the output of which gcc to the question. Which g++ has a similar output.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have added the symlink, but using g++55 instead of g++ gives the same error as above about cc1plus.

Comment: @LinAlg `stat` your `gcc` and `g++`. I have a feeling that they are symlinks.

Comment: @ajeh that would not explain why the commands work using the full path. Apparently using `~` in paths is not fully supported, see the update. I yet have to understand why, using `~` worked for me before.

Comment: So if you use `/home/username/dependenices/gcc` in the `PATH` it works?

Comment: @ajeh both in PATH and LIBRARY_PATH, yes, then it works. I can also use $HOME, just not ~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde is not expanded when quoted. Use a real variable like `$HOME` instead.

See [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Personal opinion: Use tilde freely on the command line (with the caveat that it does not expand in quotes), but use `$HOME` is scripts.

Comment: Thanks, this has to be the explanation. Oddly enough, bash expands the tilde when it uses the path variable. If Bash didn't do that, the error would have been easier to spot.

Comment: @LinAlg From the `bash` manual: _[...] one may use filenames with
       tildes in assignments to `PATH`, `MAILPATH`, and `CDPATH,` and the shell
       assigns the expanded value._  It expands the tilde when it finds it in those three variables, but it retains the actual tilde in their values. The manual is a bit hazy on that point.