# bash how to script if I expect both spaces and symbols like `~` in path variables?

Tags: bash

Why `~` does not expand in `$ ./foo.sh`?

```
MYPATH_TO=~"/Documents 2/temp"
echo ~
echo "$MYPATH_TO"
mkdir "$MYPATH_TO"
```

when run in `/home/mint/Documents 2` creates `/home/mint/Documents 2/~/Documents 2/temp` (echo outputs `/home/mint` `~/Documents 2/temp`). I have read [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes) and put `~` outside of quotes, still does not expand, why?

ADDED: it does not expand because it is quoted in `mkdir`, but then how to script if I expect both spaces and symbols like `~` in path?

ADDED 2:
when I tried `mkdir` w/out quotes for path w/out spaces:

```
MYPATH_TO=~"/Documents/temp"
mkdir $MYPATH_TO
```

I got error `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘~/Documents/temp’: No such file or directory`. Why? I have `Documents` in my home. I'm lost...

*System: Linux Mint 19.2*

Comment: Use $HOME instead of ~; then you don't have to worry about expansion.

Comment: The right side of = is considered "quoted". There is a high risk that it doesn't get expanded. One  solution is to replace "~" with `'$HOME'` with `${MYPATH_TO/#~/'$HOME'}` (in bash) or similar.

Comment: You also need to "unquote" the slash: `MYPATH_TO=~/"Documents/temp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to put the first slash outside the quoted part:

```
MYPATH_TO=~/"Documents 2/temp"
echo "$MYPATH_TO"

/home/user/Documents 2/temp
```

Another example:

```
bash -c 'a=~"/." b=~\/. c=~/. d=~/"."; echo "$a $b $c $d"'
~/. ~/. /home/user/. /home/user/.
```

Only `$c` and `$d` will have the tilde expanded in `bash`, `dash`, `mksh` and `yash`. `ksh93` will also expand it in `$a`, and `zsh` in `$a` and `$b`.

According to the POSIX [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_01) (emphasis mine):

> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted `<tilde>` character at the beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the **first unquoted `<slash>`** in the word. In an assignment [...] multiple tilde-prefixes can be used: at the beginning of the word (that is, following the equal sign of the assignment), following any unquoted colon, or both. A tilde-prefix in an assignment is terminated by **the first unquoted colon or slash**.

This is just a pointless annoyance IMHO, because despite non-conforming to its letter, it's only `ksh93` which implements what seems to be the intention, namely allowing user names containing slashes (you can escape them with backquotes in `ksh93`):

```
cat <<'EOT' >getpwnam.c
#include <pwd.h>
static struct passwd pwd = { "", "", 666, 666, "", "/hell", "" };
struct passwd *getpwnam(const char *name){ return &pwd; }
EOT
cc -Wall -shared getpwnam.c -o getpwnam.so
for sh in dash bash yash mksh zsh ksh93; do
    printf '%s\t' "$sh"
    LD_PRELOAD=./getpwnam.so HOME=nowhere \
      "$sh" -c 'echo ~q ~\/q ~"/q"'
done

dash    /hell ~/q ~/q
bash    /hell ~/q ~/q
yash    /hell ~/q ~/q
mksh    /hell ~/q ~/q
zsh     /hell nowhere/q nowhere/q
ksh93   /hell /hell nowhere/q
```