# ~ in $PATH variable ignores root folder

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

I'm using Alpine Linux in a container. I have `ENV PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH" \` in my Dockerfile

When logging into the shell I can successfully `ls ~/.local/bin` which is the same as `ls /root/.local/bin`, the target binary is there.

However which I call the binary directly or `which mybin` it won't work. After explicitly add `/root/.local/bin`, then it works.

I'm not sure why is this happening, since `~/.local/bin` and `/root/.local/bin` are the same.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit:**

The dup link gave me some idea of what was happening, but I found that wasn't the main cause. Removing quotes won't work still, as the Dockerfile `ENV` directive does not do any shell expansion.

It seems the only viable way to do this is to use `export &&` in a `CMD` directive.

Nor does `$HOME` work in `ENV` directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Comment: I think you should post the edit as an answer. I'm pretty sure variable expansion works in `ENV`, but you have to set `HOME` beforehand. Docker won't automatically set it for you.

Comment: Compare [this](https://superuser.com/a/1436281/432690) or [this](https://superuser.com/a/1418600/432690).

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure which shell you are using, assuming bash, you will need to specify `$HOME` rather than `~` as apart from the interactive command line it is not safe to use `~` anywhere else.

Some locations as in inside scripts, `~` will also work, but defining them inside a variable may have unexpected results, as you have experienced.

You can also echo back `$PATH` to see what the contents are.

```
echo $PATH
```

You will see that with your current implementation, it will include the path `~/.local/bin` instead of the self-expanded `/root/.local/bin` as `~` was taken literally.

Comment: "it is not safe to use ~ anywhere else" What's unsafe about it? On the contrary, `~` is safer than `$HOME`, since it does not undergo filename expansion:  `HOME='*'; echo $HOME; echo ~`.

Comment: @muru, what you describe is exactly what is unsafe about using `~`.  On the command line the unescaped `~` will expand to your home directory.  However, when placed inside a variable, like `PATH`, it will be taken literally.  So, the behavior changes (unexpectedly to the untrained eye). The result is that PATH will include a directory which most-likely does not exist.  In order to get proper expansion to your home directory inside variables, one wants to use `$HOME` as it expands to the user home directory (even on the command-line).

Comment: I think you and I have rather different interpretations of "unsafe."

Comment: This appears to be. In regards to variables or auto-expansion objects (like `~`) my understanding of “safe” is that while using them unescaped behaves the same way no matter where they are implemented. If the behavior changes under some methods, it may result in surprises on the result (like the one the OP voiced). Hence, I regard its use unsafe.  I am not at all talking about data safety, where with a variable (any variable really) one can delete an unintended file due lack of knowledge of its contents.  They are two different books for me.