# I cannot change directory in script using variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

_directory1="/home/user/test1"
_directory2="test2"

cd "${_directory1}/$_directory2"

for i in *
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

And here is the error:

```
./myscript.sh: 6: cd: can't cd to /home/user/test1/test2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code before edits:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

_directory1="~/test1"
_directory2="test2"

for i in $(cd "${_directory1}/$_directory2")
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

1. The tilde (`~`) does not behave like a variable.  It will, for example, not expand to the path to your home directory when used within quotes.  In a script, use `$HOME` instead of tilde. `~` is a "shortcut" that you may want to use on the command line, but `$HOME` is more descriptive in a script.

   - See "[Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)" for more information.
2. `cd` does not output anything that you can loop over, so using `cd` in a command substitution with `for` will not do you anything good. Unfortunately, it's unclear what you want your loop to actually do, so I can't give you a surefire alternative implementation.

---

The code with your edits:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

_directory1="/home/user/test1"
_directory2="test2"

cd "${_directory1}/$_directory2"

for i in *
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

This code would only output

```
"./myscript.sh: 6: cd: can't cd to /test2"
```

if you misspell the name of the variable `_directory1` (and the misspelled variable is empty, and the `/test2` directory does not exist).

---

You then edited the error message *again* to say that it outputs

```
./myscript.sh: 6: cd: can't cd to /home/user/test1/test2
```

which simply means that the directory `/home/user/test1/test2` does not exist.  You have not given evidence that this directory *does* exist so we have to take your system's word for that.

---

Here's a script that lists the contents of a directory (assuming that the directory exists). The code prints the full pathname of each file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME/test1
subdir=test2

printf '%s\n' "$topdir/$subdir"/*
```

Or,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME/test1
subdir=test2

shopt -s nullglob

for name in "$topdir/$subdir"/*; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

The `nullglob` shell option makes the loop not run at all if the given pattern does not match anything.  Without setting the `nullglob` option, the pattern would remain unexpanded if if didn't match anything, and the loop would use it as the value for `$name` in a single iteration.

You may also want to set the `dotglob` shell option (`shopt -s dotglob`) if you are interested in hidden names (filenames starting with a `.` character).

Or, without printing the full path to each filename,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME/test1
subdir=test2

cd "$topdir/$subdir" || exit 1

printf '%s\n' *
```

The `exit 1` will terminate the script if the `cd` fails.

Or,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME/test1
subdir=test2

cd "$topdir/$subdir" || exit 1

shopt -s nullglob

for name in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

To print only the filenames without their full path, without using `cd`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

topdir=$HOME/test1
subdir=test2

shopt -s nullglob

for name in "$topdir/$subdir"/*; do
    printf '%s\n' "$( basename "$name" )"

    # or:  printf '%s\n' "${name##*/}"

done
```

This uses the `basename` utility to extract only the filename portion of the pathnames.  The alternative in the comment uses a standard parameter substitution, `${name##*/}`, to delete the initial directory path before the filenames (literally "remove the longest prefix string matching the pattern `*/` from `$name`").

Comment: I understand., didn't know that. But this is not the problem. When I made this like your saying, I got the same result. I edited now.

Comment: I just want to ```cd``` a specific directory. Then do a ```for``` loop to see what's inside.

Comment: @AhmetMehmet That's not the error I get with the code that is currently in the question. Please double check your actual code for typos of the `_directory1` variable's name.

Comment: I just edited my code and still got that error.

Comment: Strangely the script is working now. Is there a way that ```for``` do the job without ```cd```?