# How to create nested folders (start with .) properly?

Tags: ubuntu, directory, mkdir

I want to create the nested folder `.aa/.bb` in the current user root's home directory. So I use the command `mkdir -p "~/.aa/.bb/"`. But it doesn't work as I expected and it created a folder `~`, which I don't know how to enter into. Below is my testing.

```
root@u2004:~# pwd
/root
root@u2004:~# ls -la
total 28
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Aug 28 14:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Aug 28 01:22 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 3285 Aug 28 21:56 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Dec  5  2019 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug  1 00:31 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  161 Dec  5  2019 .profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   89 Aug 28 14:46 setproxy.sh
root@u2004:~# mkdir -p "~/.aa/.bb/"
root@u2004:~# ls -la
total 32
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Aug 28 21:59  .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Aug 28 01:22  ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 28 21:59 '~'     <--------------------
-rw-------  1 root root 3285 Aug 28 21:56  .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Dec  5  2019  .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug  1 00:31  .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  161 Dec  5  2019  .profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   89 Aug 28 14:46  setproxy.sh
root@u2004:~# 
root@u2004:~# cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
root@u2004:~#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`~` doesn’t have a special meaning when it’s quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/86440). Thus to enter your new directory:

```
cd "~"
```

And to fix your initial `mkdir`:

```
mkdir -p ~/.aa/.bb
```