# Why does variable expansion in commands not work in ZSH but it does in BASH?

Tags: bash, zsh, variable

I have set an environment variable and want to use it when calling a command, but no dice.

The full command, without variable, works:

```
nacho@WouldntYouLikeToKnow ~ % ls -la ~/Downloads             
total 8675309
drwx------+ 16 nacho  staff        512 Sep 28 10:30 .
drwxr-x---+ 29 nacho  staff        928 Sep 29 10:39 ..
```

Now I set a variable and try to use it, but it fails:

```
nacho@WouldntYouLikeToKnow ~ % export testing="-la ~/Downloads"

nacho@WouldntYouLikeToKnow ~ % ls $testing
ls: invalid option --  
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHILOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxy1%,] [--color=when] [-D format] [file ...]
```

Comment: Is there an alias set? The command `alias ls` should tell you.

Comment: Nope. I no alias for `ls`.

Comment: Does it work if you do `export option='-la'; ls $option ~/Downloads` ?

Comment: Nope. That does not work either.

Comment: The description of why a command inside a variable doesn't work is long and has been done in many other answers. If you set `testing="-la $HOME/Downloads"` and then you execute `ls $=testing` should work in zsh. But not something that is recommended to use.

Comment: Why do you need to `export` that variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost always the wrong approach to stuff several separate strings (arguments) into a single string, at least if you need to extract those separate strings again.

What you're doing works in the `bash` shell (assuming you used `$HOME` in place of `~`, as the shell does not do tilde expansion inside double quotes) because it splits the unquoted variable expansion on the space characters in the string (on any character in `$IFS`; and also applies filename globbing to the generated words), while the `zsh` shell does not do that.

Note that it only works in `bash` since there are no *other* space, tab or newline characters in your string and since the string also does not contain filename globbing characters.  Your approach would most definitely *not* work in `bash` if the pathname had a space in it, for example, or if you want to list the contents of a directory called `*`.

The correct way to store separate command line arguments in a variable in both shells is to use an array:

```bash
args=( -la ~/Downloads )
```

or

```bash
args=( -l -A ~/Library/'Application Support' )
```

In the `bash` shell, you would then use this as

```bash
ls "${args[@]}"
```

Here, `"${args[@]}"` expands to a list consisting of the elements of the `args` array, each individually quoted.

In the `zsh` shell, you could do the same thing or just use

```bash
ls $args
```

Here, the `zsh` shell would expand the array `args` to separate elements, each turning into an argument for `ls`, but it would not (by default) split those elements or apply filename globbing to them.

These examples also leave the tilde unquoted, allowing the shell to expand it into the pathname of the user's home directory. This expansion would happen when assigning to the `args` arrays, not when using the value.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)
- [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850)

Comment: Wouldn't work in bash either as even there tilde expansion is not done upon parameter expansion.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So it is. They have probably tried to make a "neater" looking example.